# Squid 3.5.12 HTTP vs HTTPS Custom Block Page

Tags: squid

I have Squid 3.5.12 On Ubuntu Server 16.04.5 LTS

I'm using it to block everything except specific domains listed in whitelist.txt

Everything is working fine except for the blocked page shown to the user:

With **HTTP** it works just fine with `ERR_ACCESS_DENIED`. It shows that the site is blocked. I edited `/usr/share/squid/errors/fr/ERR_ACCESS_DENIED` to show a personalized message and it works as expected.

The problem here is with HTTPS, it gives `ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED`.

I want to make it show the same message as the **HTTP** does.

Is there a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using anything for reverse proxy? Like NGINX or Apache?

Answer (score 0):

The blocked page is *not* shown in the browser trying to establish the CONNECT tunnel through the proxy because browser explicitly expects only "200 Connection Established" response from proxy. All other responses (and for example 403 that is used when site is blocked) are not shown.

It is possible to allow the connection through, tell Squid to forcefully sslbump it and then show a blocked page for any request passed over that established tunnel - but you would need to have some custom ICAP/URL rewriter that does that. For example, here is how it is done in Web Safety ICAP for Squid - https://docs.diladele.com/faq/squid/cannot_connect_to_site_using_https.html